# Extra indentation for <strong> and <a>tags?

Tags: html, css

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have coded a list:

```
<h2 class="top-heading-big" style="text-align: center;">Déroulement de la Prestation</h2>
<ul style="line-height: 160%;">
<li class="presta"><a target="_blank" class="retour" href=/pages/contact title="Envoyer un email à Pascal pour recevoir un Audit" style="text-decoration: underline; color:#1990C6;">Prise de contact</a> avec votre besoin succintement décrit</li><br>
<li class="presta">Audit Vidéo de 10 min, Gratuit et Sans Engagement </li><br>
<li class="presta">Ajustement & Établissement du Devis</li><br>
<li class="presta">Réception du Paiement</li><br>
<li class="presta">Prestation livrée dans les meilleurs délais</li><br>
<li class="presta">Compte-Rendu en vidéo de 10 min, et réception du feedback client avec témoignage</li><br>
<li class="presta"><strong>Consulting Personnalisé Offert</strong> pour aller plus loin</li><br>
</ul>
<br>
```

It looks like the indentation is not regular among the different lines of my list.
In particular, the first and last lines have an extra indentation.

[image]

So I immediately thought, this is because of the  and  tags that appear right at the beginning of each lines.

I had none idea of this, could you confirm?

And if this a well-known fact, what would be the best solution to have an aquel indentation for each line?

I know I could put a new class for the first and last element, and then play with CSS to adapt this extra indentation, but I'm pretty sure there is something better.

PS: I'm using Google Chrome last version

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this matter :)

Sincerely, Pascal

URL: https://www.pascaldegut.com/pages/prestation-webdesign?variant=16668787376246

Comment: I made a fiddle and in the jsfiddle the list looks uniformly indented ? http://jsfiddle.net/bcenLpo5/ It may be related to your font choice or the type of bullet. Have you tried removing default margin/padding at the top of your css? like *{margin:0px; padding:0px;} ?

Comment: br in between li is also a problem. You should fix HTML first, then CSS if that is really the matter (li are supposed to be block element at first An extra line can be done via margin or paddding or both)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Over and over you keep posting questions lacking code that reproduce the issue you describe, and over and over I tell you not too... Here at SO we have a guide on how to post a good question, please read [ask] so you learn what that means. Furthermore, as the code fragment in this question has invalid markup, you might want to read up your skills, because I am starting to believe that that is the main reason your code doesn't work.

Comment: LGSon well, I'm sorry but I defintely don't get what is not fine... I have asked you yesterday and got no answer from you. I have done. What's wrong with "the shortest code necessary to reproduce the question itself" ? It's exactly what I have written.... I am working on my skills, it's when I can't find the answer that I prepare those questions. And since the answer look not evident (I didn't get the answers among the comments), I guess the question was not that stupid, opposed to what you imply :/
I'm still waiting you ranswer on the clarification: cause I read all the details you provided

Comment: RachelGallen, I know I can use CSS to fix this, and I know I won't have issue with a regular bullet. The post was about to know if there were a better way, and why this happened with this particular bullet (cause I couldn't find any info on it)
Sorry if I wasnot clear

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a try: remove the whitespaces in the first and last li content right at the beginning, please.

I've looked at your generated HTML Code of the given URL above. It's not the exact semantic. It's obviously not a valid html semantic. Change your code from:

```
<ul style="line-height: 160%;">
<li class="presta">
<a target="_blank" class="retour" href="/pages/contact" title="Envoyer un email à Pascal pour recevoir un Audit" style="text-decoration: underline; color:#1990C6;">Prise de contact</a> avec votre besoin succintement décrit</li>
<br>
<li class="presta">Audit Vidéo de 10 min, Gratuit et Sans Engagement </li>
<br>
<li class="presta">Ajustement &amp; Établissement du Devis</li>
<br>
<li class="presta">Réception du Paiement</li>
<br>
<li class="presta">Prestation livrée dans les meilleurs délais</li>
<br>
<li class="presta">Compte-Rendu en vidéo de 10 min, et réception du feedback client avec témoignage</li>
<br>
<li class="presta">
<strong>Consulting Personnalisé Offert</strong> pour aller plus loin</li>
<br>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<ul style="line-height: 160%;">
  <li class="presta"><a target="_blank" class="retour" href="/pages/contact" title="Envoyer un email à Pascal pour recevoir un Audit" style="text-decoration: underline; color:#1990C6;">Prise de contact</a> avec votre besoin succintement décrit</li>
  <li class="presta">Audit Vidéo de 10 min, Gratuit et Sans Engagement </li>
  <li class="presta">Ajustement &amp; Établissement du Devis</li>
  <li class="presta">Réception du Paiement</li>
  <li class="presta">Prestation livrée dans les meilleurs délais</li>
  <li class="presta">Compte-Rendu en vidéo de 10 min, et réception du feedback client avec témoignage</li>
  <li class="presta"><strong>Consulting Personnalisé Offert</strong> pour aller plus loin</li>
</ul>
```

I've also removed the `<br>`s between the `<li>` elements. For the spacing purpose you have to define a margin to the `<li>` elements. To create a valid mark up you have to remove `<br>` as direct childs of `<ul>`. If you really need this sort of break you can use it like that: `<li>some content<br></li>`

Anyway, I recommend a `margin-bottom` for this behaviour.

Comment: br direct child of ul is not allowed, you should advise to fix html first

Comment: @G-Cyr indeed, fixed my comment. Didn't see that one as part of the solution.

Comment: I know <br> is not a good practice, anyway the codes given so far do not give a nice layout at all. The best way is like I did :/
I will definitely rearrange CSS, so it looks better

But the indentation on first and last line remain a mystery for me... Too bad I'm getting downvotes from people who didn't get the subtility of my demand...
But I would like to thank you all for your replies

Comment: In the first and last element, the `<li>` and the `<a>` you have created seem to have many spaces between each other. The HTML renderer reduces them to just one, giving you the solution you've gotten so far. The other `<li>` elements don't have this spaces. By removing them in the first and last `<li>` you will remove your extra indentation.

Comment: Hello, I don't have any spaces in the first and last lines. There are some inside the <a> tags but those won't be taken into account. Anyway thanks dcballs, I have put a margin element between lines and it gives what I want (line height was not ok)